# How to parse JSON array (as a string) to Dictionary<string,string> in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, parsing, dictionary

I have a string in the following format:

```
{ "Updated" : [ { "FIRST_NAME" : "Aaa", "LAST_NAME" : "Bbb" } ] }
```

How can I get a dictionary out of this so I can call `dict["FIRST_NAME"]`?

I've tried the following, but I think they don't work because my string is a JSON *array*? If that's the case, how do I change it to a regular JSON string? I don't think it needs to be an array with the simple type of data that is in it... The size of the array will never be more than 1 - i.e., there will be no repeating fields.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonString); //didn't work

JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(jsonString); //didn't work
```

Comment: You can't (meaningfully) parse a JSON array into a dictionary.

Comment: But of course, what you have is an object (dictionary) containing a single-element array containing an object (dictionary).  Peel the onion.

Comment: @HotLicks the problem is that I don't know how to do that. Could you help?

Comment: Peel the onion.  From the initial parse you get a dictionary.  Ask for the "Updated" element of that, which will be an array.  Ask for the zeroth element of the array, which will be a dictionary.  Ask for your target values in that dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are having is a complex object, which can be parsed as a Dictionary of an Array of a Dictionary!

So you can parse it like:

```
var dic = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>[]>>(jsonString)["Updated"][0];
var firstName = dic["FIRST_NAME"];
var lastName = dic["LAST_NAME"];
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to just work with a dynamic variable.  See [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object) for more details.